# Wordpress.Enlazar secciones con iconos principales de navegación web

Tags: wordpress

Quiero enlazar los típicos botones de inicio,acerca de, productos,contáctanos que se encuentran en el encabezado de una web con las distintas secciones de la misma web, uso wordpress para ello.

Comment: Hola, haz el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).